# Android - Getting return value of a thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I start with Android and Java, and my English is not very good (sorry).
I'm doing a application which compare 2 pictures taking by the camera and return a float value = a ratio of identical pixels in the 2 pictures.

```
public static float comparePic(String img_1, String img_2){
    Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(img_1);
    Bitmap bitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(img_2);
    int equ = 0;
    //get one height and one width because we assume that pictures have always same sizes
    int h = bitmap1.getHeight();
    int w = bitmap1.getWidth();
    for(int y=0;y<h;y++){
        for (int x=0;x<w;x++){
            int pixel1 = bitmap1.getPixel(x,y);
            int pixel2 = bitmap2.getPixel(x,y);
            //alpha doesn't matter, they're jpg
            int redValue1 = Color.red(pixel1);
            int redValue2 = Color.red(pixel2);
            int greenValue1 = Color.green(pixel1);
            int greenValue2 = Color.green(pixel2);
            int blueValue1 = Color.blue(pixel1);
            int blueValue2 = Color.blue(pixel2);
            if (redValue1==redValue2 && greenValue1==greenValue2 && blueValue1==blueValue2){
                equ++;
            }
        }
    }
    return (float)equ/(h*w);
}
```

When I execute it, I have this message : "I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 730 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread."
So I tried to do it with a thread, but I'm always failing because I don't know how to return the value. 
Futhermore, by skipping frames I guess, the ratio is not correct.
I know that it's an asynchonous work, so what can I do ?
Thanks !

Comment: Could you show us how you tried to solve your problem using a thread?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a public (setter-)method in your main class (or wherever you need the value).
When your async thread is done call the method with `equ` as the parameter.

You obviously need to care about thread-safety so consider making the method sychronized.

Comment: Remember that you can't access the View from the thread different than main thread.

Answer (score 0):

You should give a try to [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). It's a class specifically prepared for background processing. It has some drawbacks (it's not good idea to do networking with AsyncTask), but for some picture comparison stuff it is a great tool.

Answer (score 0):

Define an Asynctask with a interface and implement that interface in the main Activity.

That way you can notify that host activity that the background asynctask has completed.